# Dropbox often stalls "Saving 1 file", have to restart it

Tags: dropbox

Dropbox works well, but often the tray icon starts spinning forever with the tooltip message "Saving 1 file..."
I usually don't worry about it, and I never had any loss, despite switching computers often.
An easy solution is to restart Dropbox, it spins for a second before the tooltip says "All files up to date".

But how to permanently prevent this problem?

Ubuntu 2010.10
Dropbox 0.7.110
Dropbox stores about 50 text files, 1 MB in total.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## This worked for me, you give it a try:

If unlinking and relinking your account doesn't solve the issue, your settings may be protected or inaccessible due to a permissions problem. If this is the case, you can remove your settings by hand using an administrative account. Here's how:

**On Linux**

1. Quit Dropbox by right-clicking on the Dropbox menu from the menu bar and selecting Quit
2. Open a terminal and copy and paste the following line into the terminal (exactly as written below):

   **sudo rm -rfI ~/.dropbox**
3. You will be asked for your password to confirm the folder's removal
4. Restart Dropbox from the Applications > Internet menu

Once Dropbox loads, the application will rebuild your settings files and you will be asked to relink to your account.

Note: We're working on a way to check and fix your Dropbox installation automatically from within the application. Stay tuned...

(From the Dropbox Help Forum Team)

Comment: I just unlinked and relinked, I will let a few days pass to judge whether the problem reappears or not.

Comment: The instructions of the dropbox team isn't to simply unlink and relink. You should remove a folder in order to allow your dropbox to make a new configuration of your dropbox when relinking. Which seems to have some sense since it works. In my experience: I waited 2 weeks until I found this solution. Good luck my friend!

Comment: OK, I also ran this command. Will come back for feedback in a few days.

Comment: I removed the folder, reinstalled completely, and still the same problem.

Comment: Problem does not occur anymore with recent versions. Accepting highest-voted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Go into the folder with nautilus and see which file is not being updated. The icon has a [blue symbol with two white arrows inside](http://www.metrolic.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/04/dropbox-overlay-icons_opt.jpg). Check if you have enough privileges to read the the file. I would also update to the latest client version, which is 1.1.35.